# Two-Way Data-Binding with Angular2

Tags: angular

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? I'm unable to get Angular2 2-way data-binding to work using the [(ngModel)] syntax. Here's my Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
declare let window;

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  progress: number;

  constructor(public _sharedService: SharedService) {
    window.addEventListener('progress.update', function () { # ANSWER: Change function () { to () => {
      this.progress = window.sharedService.progress;
      console.log(this.progress); # this outputs numbers
    });
  }
}
```

And here's my HTML:

```
<ion-range [(ngModel)]="progress" min="0" max="100" name="progress">
        <ion-icon range-left small name="sunny"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon range-right name="sunny"></ion-icon>
      </ion-range>
```

Shouldn't changing the value of this.progress inside the Component reflect in the view since I'm using [(ngModel)]?

Comment: maybe because of `progress` type `number`? can you make it `string` and try? I am not sure.. would be great if you provide plunkr.

Comment: just checked and progress is a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two-way-binding you need an `@Input()` and and `@Output()` where the name matches while the `@Output()`s name has an additional `Change` suffix.

```ts
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  @Input()
  progress: number;

  @Output()
  progressChange:EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(public _sharedService: SharedService) {
    window.addEventListener('progress.update', () => { // <<<=== use arrow function for `this.` to work
      this.progress = window.sharedService.progress;
      this.progressChange.emit(this.progress);
      console.log(this.progress); # this outputs numbers
    });
  }
}
```

for the event handler you can also use

```ts
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  @Input()
  progress: number;

  @Output()
  progressChange:EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  constructor(public _sharedService: SharedService) {}

  @HostListener('window:progress.update')
  onProgressUpdate() {
    this.progress = window.sharedService.progress;
    this.progressChange.emit(this.progress);
    console.log(this.progress); # this outputs numbers
  }
}
```

Comment: what would the HTML look like? also, doesn't this defeat the purpose of [(ngModel)]?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with HTML. `[(ngModel)]` does 2-way-binding. Where should this be reflected in the view?

Comment: shouldn't 2-way data-binding already bind it to the component class as well?

Comment: it's supposed to be the part that says [(ngModel)]="progress"

Comment: I don't get what the problem is

Comment: I guess it's just `function () {` as mentioned in the code in my answer.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand.. what's the difference between what you recommended and just using [(ngModel)] to set all that up automatically?

Comment: The `@Input()` / `@Output()` stuff is for implementing custom two-way-binding like `<my-tabs [(progress)]="progressInParent"`. I didn't fully understand your question.

Comment: when would you need to use that?

Comment: When you want two-way-binding between two components. `ngModel` is only for form-controls.

Comment: it looks like I have to use addEventListener since I'm adding this to a service... do you know how I can access this.progress inside the function that addEventListener uses?

Comment: Right, `@HostListener()` only works in components and directives. Not sure what you mean. If you use `() => {...}` `this...` should just work.

Comment: using angular 6, I am getting the array of images from http request and pushing into array and displaying using ngfor . for the first set it works and after the page scroll dynamic fetching of images not working. Fetching of text is working dynamically on scroll also  Can you tell me why.

Comment: @ThilakRaj I'd suggest to create a new question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054052/two-way-data-binding-of-images-using-ngfor-in-angular-6