# Two way data binding of images using ngFor in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6, two-way-binding

I am using angular 6 and  [infinite scroll](https://github.com/orizens/ngx-infinite-scroll). Requesting the data using http service, I am able to bind the data(images) to dom on init. But I am fetching the next number of records on scroll end using infinite scroll. On scroll of I am triggering the function and pushing to the same array, and it is reflecting in ts(checked using debugger). But not binding in Html. It may be possible duplicate, But no solutions helped me. and also please give the correct way of debounce method implementation in angular 6 can anyone please help

 
**Html**

```
<section class="main-container"  infiniteScroll infiniteScrollUpDistance]="1" 
[infiniteScrollThrottle]="300" (scrolled)="onScroll($event)">
 <ul class="grid-wrap">

  <li *ngFor="let image of flickrImages">
    <img [attr.src]="image.url_m" alt="Image not found" onerror="this.src='https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/f752abb3-1b49-4f99-b68a-7c4d77b45b40_1.39d6c524f6033c7c58bd073db1b99786.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF';" >
  </li>
</ul>
</section>
```

**ts**

```
reqObj : any = {
   per_page : 5,
   pageNo: 1,
   query: ''
 }
getImages(fromScroll){
this.reqObj['query'] = this.searchKeyword ? this.searchKeyword : '';
this.flickrService.getImages(this.reqObj).subscribe((res) => {
  if(res && res['stat'] ==='ok'){
    if(fromScroll){
      this.flickrImages.push(...res['photos']['photo'])          
      this.reqObj.pageNo++;
    } else{
      this.flickrImages = res['photos']['photo'];
      this.totalPages = res['photos']['pages']
    }
  }
 },(error) => {
   console.log(error);
 });
}
onScroll(ev) {
  if(ev.currentScrollPosition>=document.documentElement.scrollHeight && 
this.reqObj.pageNo < this.totalPages ){
    this.getImages(true);
   }
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
// import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
 export class FlickrService {
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  ApiUrl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?extras=url_m&api_key=4df09ecd4fb22d6b29e03658dfbca36f&format=json&nojsoncallback=1";
  getImages(reqObj){
    if(reqObj.query){
      return this.http.get(this.ApiUrl+'&per_page='+ reqObj.per_page+'&text='+reqObj.query+'&page='+reqObj.pageNo+'&method=flickr.photos.search');
    } else {
      return this.http.get(this.ApiUrl+'&per_page='+ reqObj.per_page+'&page='+reqObj.pageNo+'&method=flickr.photos.getRecent');
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Where you called get images method. Provide more code related details.

Comment: @KarnanMuthukumar I have added more code.